# J'ai regardé des vidéos d'« instant karma fails » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Certains vidéos qu'on trouve sur un site d'hébergement bien connu sont identifiés sous le vocable « *[instant](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=instant&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) [karma](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/karma) [fails](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fail?s=t)* » [((instant karma) fails) ; mot à mot *échecs de karma instantané* mais avec [*fails*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fails&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) d'un registre au moins *informel*] ; on y voit, par exemple, quelqu'un essayer de bousculer une autre personne et spontanément se planter elle-même, ou des voleurs essayer de *braquer* un commerce mais ne pas faire le poids du tout face au commerçant, etc. On connaît le mot provenant du sanscrit *karma* en français, mais surtout comme concept et peu de manière usuelle, semble-t-il ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/karma/45365?q=karma#45308), [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/karma)).

---

> J'ai regardé des vidéos de/d' [*instant karma fails*].

A-t-on mieux qu'*échecs de karma instantané* (lexique, tournure, expression) ?

Comment: je dirais "retour de karma instantané" en référence au retour de flammes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si j'ai bien compris le concept, il s'agit simplement d'[arroseurs arrosés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Arroseur_arros%C3%A9).

L'expression est particulièrement pertinente dans ce contexte puisqu'il s'agit du titre d'un des tous premiers films de l'histoire du cinéma.

Comment: Effectivement tu as bien compris le concept, le protagoniste "commet une farce qui se retourne contre lui". Cependant le film en question manque malheureusement un composant de l'humour du "instant karma", c'est que normalement le farceur ne devait pas prévoir ce qui lui arrive. La fessée du jardinier c'est un peu trop prévisible !

Comment: Le film avait une vocation humoristique, et a sûrement fait beaucoup rire de son temps. On est sûrement bien plus exigeants maintenant qu'aux tout débuts du cinéma.

Comment: @Law29: C'est vrai pour le film, mais l'expression est devenue plus générale.

Answer (score 3):

En fait, "instant karma fail" comporte deux parties distinctes : "instant karma" et "fail".

"instant karma" -> "instant karmic retribution" -> retour de karma instantané.

Le retour de karma est un coup du sort qui punit celui qui a mal agit (ou plus rarement récompense celui qui a bien agit).
Le fait qu'il soit instantané lui donne un effet cocasse. Pour qu'il s'agisse réellement d'un "retour de karma" il faut que la punition ne soit pas une vengeance, mais plutôt un coup du sort. En cela on a une différence avec l'arroseur arrosé car dans ce dernier cas c'est souvent la victime qui retourne la situation de manière active alors que pour l'instant karma quand la victime est impliquée elle n'a pas besoin d'agir de manière active. Par exemple les situations suivantes sont des "instant karma":

- Quelqu'un place un seau d'eau sur une porte, mais sa manche reste coincée dans la poignée et le seau lui tombe dessus.
- Quelqu'un en pousse un autre dans la neige, puis rit tellement qu'il perd l'équilibre et se vautre aussi.

Celles-ci n'en sont pas:

- Clown1 lance une tarte à la crème sur Clown2. Ce dernier lui en lance deux en représailles.

"fail" -> littéralement "échec" mais repris en tant que tel pour désigner une scène durant laquelle un personnage échoue de manière particulièrement ridicule. Par exemple les scènes suivantes sont des "fails":

- Une personne obèse décide de faire du vélo d'appartement pour perdre du poids, mais le vélo casse.
- Un balayeur met une heure à rassembler les feuilles d'une allée, met un ventilateur pour se rafraichir, et toutes les feuilles s'envolent à nouveau.

Bien entendu les deux concepts peuvent très bien se coller sur la même scène, auquel cas on a à la fois un "fail" et un "instant karma". Notez aussi que le milieu des vidéos en ligne n'est pas celui où les "écrivains" sont les plus respectueux des normes, il est donc très fréquents de trouver des vidéos qualifiées à tort de "instant karma fail".

---

Proposition de traduction:

*Échec de karma instantané* est un contre-sens, car ici ce n'est pas le karma qui échoue mais la personne dans la vidéo. Pour garder les mêmes termes on pourrait dire *échec : karma instantané* ou *échec dû au karma instantané*.

Comment: À mon avis la restriction excluant la vengeance est plus stricte que l'exemple des voleurs donné dans la question. De plus l'expression _arroseur arrosé_ va au-delà du film et n'implique pas nécessairement de vengeance.

Comment: édité pour tenir compte de ce commentaire.

Answer (score 3):

En français, on peut parler de karma dans les situations qui correspondent à celles des vidéos.

> C'est le karma!

Mais ça reste une expression récente et qui n'est pas comprise par tous, il y a des chances de ne pas être compris si on essaie d'utiliser le mot karma.

Mais il existe des expressions idiomatiques pour désigner exactement la même chose :

> Le retour de flamme
>   Le retour de bâton

Ils signifient exactement la même chose, c'est le revers quasi-immédiat d'une action qui vient de se produire.
(Il faut s'imaginer quelqu'un qui tape avec un bâton, mais dont le bâton rebondit)

> Rendre à quelqu'un la monnaie de sa pièce

Plus situationnel : Se dit d'une action de vengeance dans laquelle une personne fait subir à une autre le même sort qu'il lui a fait subir, ou un châtiment considéré comme équivalent par des tiers. Cela correspond assez souvent à des karma fails.

Au final, l'idée de **Karma** se traduit par l'idée de **Retour**.

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi il ne faut pas essayer d'associer "karma" et "fails" en traduisant "échecs de karma". On a deux choses : un "fail" c'est un littéralement un échec, je traduirais "un raté" ou "plantage". C'est très utilisé pour décrire un style de vidéos où on voit des gens faire des ratés plus ou moins spectaculaires. "Karma" c'est à prendre comme l'effet qu'ont tes actions passées sur ta vie future, et ici "instant karma" signifie que l'effet de ta (mauvaise) action te rattrape instantanément. "Instant Karma" c'est donc un sous-genre du genre de vidéo "fails" : on voit quelqu'un commettre une mauvaise action, et justice (poétique, policière...) sévit immédiatement d'une façon plus ou moins prévisible. Ce n'est pas le karma qui subit un échec, c'est ta mauvaise karma qui conduit à ton plantage.

Pour une traduction, j'ai bien peur que "fail" soit déjà bien ancré dans le langage adolescent. Je pense que je dirais simplement des vidéos de karma instantané, car il y en a peu ou c'est une bonne action qui est mise en avant !

Comment: Pour information, le contraire d'un "fail", c'est un "win". Google me donne 239000 réponses pour "instant karma fails" et 32600 pour "instant karma wins".

Answer (score 1):

*Karma* est réservé à la destinée personnelle dans son acception courante.

On peut revenir aux bandes dessinées dont les héros ne réussissent rien :

> J'ai regardé des vidéos de pieds nickelés !
>
> Ah les gogoles, ils ont raté leur attaque !

- *Les gogoles* ou *Les pieds nickelés* à la télé.

Comment: Ok pour « pieds nickelés » mais j'éviterais absolument d'utiliser « gogoles », mot qui n'a aucun lien avec l'écrivain russe.

Comment: Perso, je ne connais aucune de ces références...